# Delete all new lines in bash variable with operators

Tags: bash

I want to delete all new lines and whitespaces from a string in bash script. (Like a trim() function in php)

I try this (without sed):

```
STR="home
kit
car
"
OUT=${STR//\n/}
echo $OUT
```

output

```
 home kit car
```

And I need

```
homekitcar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an incorrect way to specify the new-line character in `bash`. There is an [ANSI C-style](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) quoting syntax allowed like `$'\n'`, `$'\t'`. So specify the new-line character accordingly and do the replacement,

```
str="home
kit
car
"
out=${str//$'\n'/}
echo "$out"
homekitcar
```

Note:- Not relevant in the context of current question, but it is a good practice to lowercase all your script variables as I have shown above, upper-casing is meant for only environment variables in `bash`.

Comment: works great! 

Note that the echo works with $out instead of $OUT :)

Thanks a lot!